# Is every closed operator a bijection?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, closed-graph

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A$ be a closed linear operator on $H$. Can we conclude that $A$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal D(A)$ and $H$?

My intuition is that this is clearly wrong, but this seems to be what's been claimed in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZYAW5D8xI1MC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22As+we+saw+in+the+general+theory+of+unbounded+operators+this+property%22&source=bl&ots=QbSXsQXGiM&sig=ACfU3U2Ve1TrxjVIVftYudvUI1WUtOsIjw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCse7zl5XqAhXL-KQKHU6aD0YQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22As%20we%20saw%20in%20the%20general%20theory%20of%20unbounded%20operators%20this%20property%22&f=false) after the proof of Lemma IV.5.3. While they particularly consider the Stokes operator, they claim that the isomorphismness follows by the fact that $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any bounded opearator whose domain is the whole of $H$ is closed. So the zero operator is a counter-example.

Comment: So is the cited book quote wrong or do you think they use some additional assumption which holds in their particular case with the Stokes operator?

Comment: There must be some additional assumptions.